# How to Store the Cypress Run Result into Variable

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, test-results

I am using Cypress with Cucumber-preprocessor ,I need to store the result of Cypress Run that get printed in the console after execution
I need to pass this data to api call

Below is the example of Cypress Run Result - test case pass, fail, time taken etc (i need to capture this data into variable to pass to api

```
  2 passing (34s)


  (Results)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        2                                                                                │
  │ Passing:      2                                                                                │
  │ Failing:      0                                                                                │
  │ Pending:      0                                                                                │
  │ Skipped:      0                                                                                │
  │ Screenshots:  0                                                                                │
  │ Video:        true                                                                             │
  │ Duration:     33 seconds                                                                       │
  │ Spec Ran:     Test.feature                                                               │
```

any way to achieve this ??

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api).

This is essentially an expanded version of `npx cypress run...` that gives you easy access to the results (and errors) of the run for further processing.

Note that `results` are not formatted for the console, but that may suit your requirement better.

**Node script called e2e-run-tests.js**

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

cypress
  .run({
    // the path is relative to the current working directory
    spec: './cypress/e2e/examples/actions.cy.js',
  })
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      ...

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access each test case result with this.currentTest.state

So, to achieve what you are describing I would get each test case result inside an afterEach hook (you need to make sure that your afterEach method is not written in arrow function format) and I would store those results somewhere. At the end Cypress run I would send them to the API.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But there's a huge difference between `this.currentTest.state` and the results you get from the module API.